# How Do I Get The Events In Between Start and End Time To Display On My Calendar

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm using a tutorial I found online...and it's mostly working...I'm stuck when I'm trying to loop through the list of events and show them on a daily basis.  If I have an event that starts on June 1 and ends on June 5th...I'd like to be able to show the event on June 2 on my list and June 3 and June 4.  Currently I can only get it to say it starts on June 1 and ends on June 5.  I've tried multiple different filters utilizing GTE and LTE and that doesn't seem to help.

Here's my Calendar utility...

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None, dropdown=None):
        self.dropdown = dropdown
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
    # filter events by day
    def formatday(self, day, events):
        events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day__lte=day, end_time__day__gte=day)
        d = ''
        for event in events_per_day:
            d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'

        if day != 0:
            return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'

    # formats a week as a tr
    def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:
            week += self.formatday(d, events)
        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

    # formats a month as a table
    # filter events by year and month
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        events = VacationRequest.objects.filter(vacation_calendar=self.dropdown,start_time__year=self.year,start_time__month=self.month).order_by('start_time')
        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        cal += f'</table>\n'
        cal += f'<h1 class="title">Vacation Schedule For {self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}</h1>\n'
        return cal
```

Here's my view...

```
class VacationRequestCalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = VacationRequest
    template_name = 'vacation_request_calendar_view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dropdown = (self.request.GET.get("dropdown", None))
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month, dropdown)
        cal.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        vacation_calendar = VacationCalendar.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get("dropdown", None))
        vacation_calendar_requests = VacationRequest.objects.filter(start_time__year = d.year,start_time__month = d.month)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['dropdown'] = dropdown
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['vacation_calendar_requests'] = vacation_calendar_requests
        context['vacation_calendar'] = vacation_calendar
        return context

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(VacationCalendar, id=self.request.GET.get("dropdown"))       

def get_date(req_month):
    if req_month:
        year, month = (int(x) for x in req_month.split('-'))
        return date(year, month, day=1)
    return datetime.today()

def prev_month(d):
    first = d.replace(day=1)
    prev_month = first - timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(prev_month.year) + '-' + str(prev_month.month)
    return month

def next_month(d):
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1]
    last = d.replace(day=days_in_month)
    next_month = last + timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(next_month.year) + '-' + str(next_month.month)
    return month
```

And here's my Django Template Logic...

```
 {% if vacation_calendar_requests %}

    {% for request in vacation_calendar_requests %}

      <div class="leftwidth87">
      {% ifchanged request.start_time|date:"M d, Y" %}
      <h2>{{ request.start_time|date:"M d, Y" }}</h2>
       {% endifchanged %}
        <div>
          <h2><a href="{% url 'VacationRequests:vacation_request_detail' pk=request.pk %}">{{ request.vacation_request_name }}
          {{ request.start_time }} -
          {{ request.end_time }}</a></h2>
        </div>
      </div>

    {% endfor ifchanged %}

  {% else %}

    <div class="title">
      <h2>No Vacation Scheduled</h2>
    </div>

  {% endif %}
```

The code above will properly display events that span multiple days on a calendar...That's attributed to the formatday function.  I see how it correctly filters the events by day...I just can't figure out how to do the same thing when I try to print out the events by day via my template logic.

I get that I'm only finding 2 events with my template loop...the way that I'm going about it...but how could I loop through and find events by day instead of just their range ( start time and end time ? )

Add on...

I found an example online of how to do what I am trying to do..but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into my code above...the example I found is...

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

start_dt = date(2015, 12, 20)
end_dt = date(2016, 1, 11)
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

And it came from https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/date-time-exercise/python-date-time-exercise-50.php

But I can't figure out how to incoporate it...

Update...

I've gotten a bit closer by updating the Calendar utility...by adding the following code to the format month.

```
for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
    if events:
        # cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        return cal
```

I'm almost there...except it's printing an additional number from the calendar format...I'm also still trying to get the month and date and year to print out in a reasonable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would calculate the duration (number of days), and then use that duration as the number of times to loop. Then to get the date for each day of the duration, I would use a counter variable (enumerator maybe) and add it to the date. For example when the counter is 2, then I would add 2 days to the start date to get the current date in the loop.

Hopefully this would give you an idea.

Using your example, add this to your view:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

# Add this function outside the View, just like you did with the other ones
def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ## other code here ##
    vacation_calendar_requests = VacationRequest.objects.filter(start_time__year = d.year,start_time__month = d.month)
    
    # this will add a new field, "dates", to each event
    for request in vacation_calendar_requests:
        start_date = request.start_time
        end_date = request.end_time
        start_dt = date(start_date.year,start_date.month,start_date.day) # not sure if this is how you get your event start date
        end_dt = date(end_date.year,end_date.month,end_date.day) # not sure if this is how you get your event end date
        request.dates = [date for date in daterange(start_dt, end_dt)] 
    
    ## rest of code here ##
```

Then in your template, add this nested loop to show the dates for each event:

```
{% for date in request.dates %}
   {{ request.vacation_request_name }}
   {{ date }} /* format the date accordingly */
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a library named [datetimerange](https://pypi.org/project/DateTimeRange/) . When an event is created, you can get the start and end datetime (which you are already doing), and pass it into the DateTimeRange function and store it as a string in DB.

When you get the event back. You can get the datetime values again. Here's a piece of code from the documentation of library:

```
import datetime
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange

time_range = DateTimeRange("2015-01-01T00:00:00+0900", "2015-01-04T00:00:00+0900")
for value in time_range.range(datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
    print(value)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm trying to avoid extra libraries if I can at all help it...how painful would this be to solve with my own code or a native Python/Django approach?